# AWS EC2 instance gives 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a few Elastic Beanstalk environments. It took a while for me to get the first working, and then I replicated my settings to create the others. However, I am unable to get past a 502 error that the load balancer target health check gives, and it's the same if I try to load the app.

I checked the instance and load balancer security groups, and the settings match between the working and non-working environments (with the exception that the instance inbound source comes from the respective load balancer security group). The VPC settings are all the same. Among the non-working environments, I have apps in both availability zones 1a and 1b. The working environment is in 1a.

The Elastic Beanstalk app versions are the same. Elastic Beanstalk creates a load balancer per environment, so each environment has a different load balancer (I chose application load balancer).

I can SSH into the EC2 instances for both working and non-working environments.
Curling my working environment health check URL succeeds: curl -i -k https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/health
Curling my non-working environment health check URL fails: curl -i -k https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/health with a response that says "curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xxx port 443: Connection refused."

I double-checked the HTTPS settings for the EC2 and load balancer security groups, and they both have the appropriate inbound/outbound settings (as mentioned, the working and nonworking environments match). The environments both have a single load balancer listener for port 443 with a self-signed certificate using security policy ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08, and the target group looks on port 443 for the port and health check.

I looked at the Elastic Beanstalk logs and didn't see anything noteworthy.
From the nginx elastic beanstalk logs I see: xx.xx.xx.xx - - [19/Feb/2020:13:23:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1410 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"

In the eb-docker logs for the working app, I also see:

2/13/2020, 9:22:13 PM - �[32minfo�[39m: req -  /health
�[0mGET /health �[32m200 �[0m14.449 ms - 56�[0m

(the req - /health being a log in the app for when the path doesn't match the specified app paths, in case of a 404).

I don't see this for the non-working environment.

I'm not sure what else to check or how to resolve this.

Comment: Both environements using different load balancers or same? Also which kind of load balancer it is?

Comment: @RohanMehto I updated my post.

 Elastic Beanstalk creates a load balancer per environment, so each environment has a different load balancer (I chose application load balancer).

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with ssl redirection or something. That can happen when using ALBs. Compare you ALB rules for both the load balancers, the working one and the non working one.

Comment: @RohanMehto They are the same, that I can tell.